# Unknown predicate values error while rendering mako template in pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid, pylons, mako

I am getting **ConfigurationError('Unknown predicate values: %r' % (kw,))** while rendering mako template. Below is the structure of my pyramid project.

My pyramid project tree.

```
|-- web
|-- myweb
    |-- templates
        |-- index.mak
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- views.py
|-- development.ini
|-- production.ini
```

**web/myweb/views.py**

```
class Main(object):
def __init__(self, request):
    self.request = request
def __call__(self):
    return {}
```

**web/myweb/__*init*__.py**

```
config.add_route('main', '/',
                 view='myweb.views.Main',
                 renderer='index.mako')
```

This where i am getting error such as

```
 raise ConfigurationError('Unknown predicate values: %r' % (kw,))
 pyramid.exceptions.ConfigurationExecutionError: <class   pyramid.exceptions.ConfigurationError'>: Unknown predicate values: {'renderer': 'index.mako', 'view': 'myweb.views.Main'}
  in: Line 33 of file /home/user/project/web/myweb/__init__.py:
renderer='index.mako')
```

Here are my .ini files

**development.ini**

```
[app:myweb]
mako.directories = web:myweb:templates
```

**production.ini**

```
[app:myweb]
mako.directories = web:myweb:templates
```

I don't know what i am missing and cause of this error.

Answer (score 0):

To state the obvious, `__init__.py` refers to the template "index.mako" whereas the file is called "index.mak".